# Why the parent height is not the same is inner image height?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on css for a while, but I was confused why the parent height is not the same as the inner image height, given the following code.

```
<div style="width:200px">
    <img style="max-width:100%;" src="http://localhost:8888/example/06f1e47fbdb03e48203ebfba/66932afa697bdbc76a1a291e/thumb_d90ab4a531969620e2c2a160.jpg">
</div>
```

I was expect that the parent div would expand correspondingly with different image. The fact is that the inner image is 200*200, and the outer div is 200*206, and I have no idea where does the extra 6 pixels comes from. **There is are padding for the outer div or margin for the inner image**. Could someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Right-click in your browser, inspect element, find the element, and see what CSS is applied.

Comment: @L4zl0w I have tried it already, nothing appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bntvdsvc/2/) fix the problem for you? If not, what browser and OS are you using?

I've run into this before. The issue is that images, by default, are `display: inline-block`, which causes them to behave like text (following the text baseline for example). In cases where we do not want this to happen, we can change the display to `display: block`.

Comment: Perfect! It fixed. The same is when you have several inline-block divs , they usually get some unexpected margin between one and the other

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain why this happens?

Because the image is a replaced *inline element*, and as such it is per default aligned on the *baseline* of potential text content on the same line.

Making it `block` as already mentioned in another answer, or specifying `vertical-align:bottom` for it changes that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block;`

```css
div {
  width:200px
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://cadizinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/water_07-610x370.jpg">
</div>
```